Image of a line and a plane through affine map
Let $f:\mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3, f(x,y,z) = (x+y+z,2x-y+3,3x+z+1)$, $$\pi : x+y-z = 1$$
and $$d:\frac{x-1}{2} = \frac{y-1}{0} = \frac{z}{3}.$$
I want to find $f(d)$ and $f(\pi)$.

I found that $f(x,y,z)=\begin{pmatrix}1 & 1 & 1\\2 & -1 & 0 \\ 3 & 0 & 1\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{pmatrix} + \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 3 \\ 1\end{pmatrix}$ so it is an affine map. I found somewhere that if $A,B \in \mathbb{R}^3$ with $A \ne B$ then $f(d) = Af(f(A),f(B))$ (where $Af$ is affine hull) and if $A \ne B \ne C \ne A$ are 4 affine independent points from $\mathbb{R}^3$ then $f(\pi) = Af(f(A),f(B),f(C))$. But I don't know why this works. It is general for any k-dimensional affine subspaces from $\mathbb{R}^n$? Thanks!

in $d$, what is that divided by zero?!

$\frac{y-1}{0}$ means that $y = 1$. It's a convention

Hint
We can parameterize the line $d$ as
$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}1+2t\\1+t\\3t\end{bmatrix}, \qquad t \in \mathbb{R}.$$
Now we can find
$$f(d)=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 1 & 1\\
2 & -1 & 0\\ 
3 & 0 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}1+2t\\1+t\\3t\end{bmatrix} + \begin{bmatrix}0 \\3\\ 1 \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2+6t\\4+3t\\4+9t\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2\\4\\4\end{bmatrix}+t\begin{bmatrix}6\\3\\9\end{bmatrix}
$$
So, the image of line $d$ is the line that passes through the point $(2,4,4)$ and has direction vector as $(6,3,9)$.
Try extending this idea for the plane $\pi$.

Ok. I understand. But if that vector $(2,1,3)$ has image $0$ for one affine map $f$? Then the image is not a line.

Thanks for hint. But I want to know if for 2 affine independent points from that line (let them be $A$ and $B$) then $Af(A,B)$ is exact the image of the line. And if this works why it works?

$\pi = \{(x,y,x+y-1)\mid x,y \in R\} \implies$
$$f(\pi) = 
\{(2x+2y+1,
2x-y+3,
4x+y)\mid x,y \in R\}
$$
Now, we can find the normal vector defining the plane $f(\pi)$.
